# Триггер для предотвращения дублирования данных (MySql)

Tags: mysql, база-данных, триггер

у меня есть таблица в базе данных которая выглядит следующим образом :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fruit(
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FruitType VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
DealerCountry VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
Count INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);
```

Я хочу написать триггер, который поможет мне избежать дублирования.

Например если у меня в БД есть строка

| ID | FruitType | DealerCountry | Price | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Яблоко | Польша | 20 | 30 |

И я делаю
`INSERT INTO Fruit(FruitType,DealerCountry,Price,Count) VALUES ('Яблоко','Польша',20, 40)`, то моя существующая строка должно обновиться и стать

| ID | FruitType | DealerCountry | Price | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Яблоко | Польша | 20 | 70 |

Простым языком, если при INSERT'e значения, кроме количества, совпадают с какой-либо строкой в таблице то мы обновляем количество в этой самой существующей строке.

Comment: Для защиты от дублирования данных следует в первую очередь использовать уникальный индекс

Comment: Триггер тут нафиг не нужен. Нужен уникальный индекс и [`INSERT .. ODKU`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Я так понимаю под уникальным индексом вы имеете ввиду Uniqe(ID), но он у меня AUTO_INCREMENT, и на программном уровне я не даю возможности пользователю вводить ID руками, именно поэтому я и хочу чтобы у меня был триггер который обновит Count P.S : Я только разбираюсь в MySQL, и не до конца разобрался в каких случаях, что использовать

Comment: Неправильно понимаете. Уникальный индекс должен быть по тому полю, набору полей или выражению, по которому нужно избежать дублирования. В данном случае, вероятно, по `(FruitType, DealerCountry, Price)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> -- Исходная таблица
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fruit(
> Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> FruitType VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
> DealerCountry VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
> Price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
> `Count` INT NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY(Id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> -- Создание уникального индекса, необходимого для корректного определения дублирования
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON Fruit (FruitType, DealerCountry, Price);
> ```

> ```
> -- Добавление записей
> INSERT INTO Fruit(FruitType, DealerCountry, Price, `Count`) 
> VALUES 
> ('Яблоко','Польша',20, 40),  -- новая запись
> ('Груша','Польша',25, 50),   -- новая запись
> ('Яблоко','Польша',20, 60),  -- дубликат первой записи
> ('Груша','Польша',25, 70),   -- дубликат второй записи
> ('Яблоко','Польша',30, 80)   -- новая запись (цена отличается)
> -- если обнаружено дублирование - обновить существующую запись
> ON DUPLICATE KEY 
> UPDATE `Count` = `Count` + VALUES(`Count`);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Fruit;
> ```
>
> | Id | FruitType | DealerCountry | Price | Count |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Яблоко | Польша | 20 | 100 |
> | 2 | Груша | Польша | 25 | 120 |
> | 3 | Яблоко | Польша | 30 | 80 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=958f238943e97cac3a196828c8bb5f0e)*

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё максимально понятно и развёрнуто